# ClassNotFoundException on connecting MariaDB using Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to connect Spark to MariaDB and I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver

Now before you mark it as duplicate, I know what the error means and I've read different threads but with no success.

This is my `build.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

name := "SparkJdbc"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2",
    "org.mariadb.jdbc" % "mariadb-java-client" % "1.5.2"
)
```

I also have the jar seperately and I've tried

```
spark-submit --class SparkJdbc target/scala-2.11/sparkjdbc_2.11-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
--jars /path/to/mariadb-java-client-1.5.2.jar
```

but this also failed with the same error.

The following is the code I am using to connect

```
val (driver, url, username, password) = ("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db1", "user", "password");

Class.forName(driver).newInstance;

val data = spark.sqlContext.read
    .format("jdbc")
    .option("url", url)
    .option("user", username)
    .option("password", password)
    .option("dbtable", "SELECT * FROM db1.football LIMIT 10")
    .load();
```

Comment: `/path/to/mariadb-java-client-1.5.2.jar` Can you be a bit more specific? Did you just give the local-to-the-driver filepath,, or prefix it with something? (`local`, `http` etc). If you make logging a bit more verbose, can you see Spark loading the mariadb jars?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I am using the `--jars` command line argument to give the local filepath to the driver.

Comment: So can you see in the driver logs that it finds and loads the jar?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I got this when i set `rootCategory` to `ALL` "**INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/~/Downloads/mariadb-java-client-1.5.2.jar at spark://ip:port/jars/mariadb-java-client-1.5.2.jar with timestamp 1482248249212**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible errors:

1. `--jars` should be used before jar name. From [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), about arguments after Jar name:

> Arguments passed to the main method of your main class, if any

2. File should be on the same path on all nodes or located in distributed file system like HDFS - if you got file only in the master or driver, then application will raise error

Edit:

You [should](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases) also set `--driver-class-path=/path/to/jar/with/driver.jar`

Other option, taken from docs, is:

> The JDBC driver class must be visible to the primordial class loader
>   on the client session and on all executors. This is because Java’s
>   DriverManager class does a security check that results in it ignoring
>   all drivers not visible to the primordial class loader when one goes
>   to open a connection. **One convenient way to do this is to modify
>   compute_classpath.sh on all worker nodes to include your driver JARs.**

Comment: I moved the `--jars` declaration before and now I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver`

Comment: @philantrovert See update - additional parameter may be required